# Como llenar automáticamente cajas de texto a partir de una búsqueda?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Tengo un input text llamado "buscar" donde se debe ingresar el nombre de un cliente previamente almacenado en una tabla en mysql, quiero que al escribir un nombre salgan las coincidencias o los registros que tengo guardados en la tabla "clientes" y que al seleccionarlo, en cajas de texto salga su otra información.

Por ejemplo, en mi tabla clientes tengo los campos (id, nombre_cliente,direccion_cliente, telef_cliente y correo_cliente) y que al buscar un nombre salga en automático la información que tienen.

**¿Cómo lo puedo hacer? ¿qué necesito?**

Anteriormente tenía mi código que al buscar un registro por nombre me salía una tabla con la demás info, pero ahora ¿cómo lo hago con inputs?
Les dejo mi código anterior

```html
<? include("config.php");
 //Instaciamos la clase de base de datos
  $db = new Clasedb();
  //Llamamos a la funcion para conectar a la base de datos
  $db->MySQL();
  //Consultamos la tabla regis
  $consulta = $db->consulta("SELECT R.Nombre, R.Direccion, R.Telefono, R.Id_trabajo, R.Cantidad, R.Fecha_ingreso, R.Anticipo, T.nombre, T.costo , R.Cantidad*T.Costo AS Total, R.Cantidad*T.Costo-R.Anticipo AS Resta   FROM regis AS R JOIN trabajos AS T ON R.id_trabajo = T.id WHERE R.Nombre LIKE '%$buscar%'");
 ?>

<form class="form-horizontal" name="form1" method="post" action="consultar.php">
  
<div class="col-md-5">
 <input  class="form-control" type="text" name="buscar" placeholder="nombre del cliente">
 </div>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-primary">BUSCAR</button>

 
 
 
 <?php
 
 if($_POST['buscar'])
 {
  ?>
  <br>
 
 <div class="table-responsive">
 <div class="container" id="container1" style="padding-top: 1em;">
     <table class="table table-hover  table-condensed">
        <thead>
    <tr>
  
     <th class="col-sm-1">Nombre</th>
     <th class="col-sm-1">Direcc</th>
     <th class="col-sm-1">Tel</th>
     <th class="col-sm-1">Fecha de ingreso</th>
     <th class="col-sm-1">Id_trabajo</th>
     <th class="col-sm-1">Nombre trabajo</th>
     <th class="col-sm-1">Costo</th>
     <th class="col-sm-1">Cantidad</th>
     <th class="col-sm-1">Total</th>
     <th class="col-sm-1">Anticipo</th>
     <th class="col-sm-1">Resta</th>
     <th class="col-sm-1">Editar</th>
     <th class="col-sm-1">Eliminar</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
 <?php
 while($resultado = $db->obtenerfilas($consulta))
  
  {?>
      <tr>
     <td class="Nombre"><?=$resultado['Nombre']?></td>
     <td class="Direccion"><?=$resultado['Direccion']?></td>
     <td class="Telefonos"><?=$resultado['Telefono']?></td>
     <td class="Costo_uni"><?=$resultado['Fecha_ingreso']?></td>
     <td class="Fecha_ingreso"><?=$resultado['Id_trabajo']?></td>
     <td class="Anticipo"><?=$resultado['nombre']?></td>
     <td clas="Resta"><?=$resultado['costo']?></td>
     <td class="Tipo_trabajo"><?=$resultado['Cantidad']?></td>
     <td class="Costo_uni"><?=$resultado['Total']?></td>
     <td class="Costo_uni"><?=$resultado['Anticipo']?></td>
     <td class="Costo_uni"><?=$resultado['Resta']?></td>
     
     <td class="Editar"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dataUpdate" data-id="<?php echo $row['id']?>"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></i></button></td>
             

             <td class="Eliminar"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dataDelete" data-id="<?php echo $row['id']?>"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></i></button></td>
  
    </tr>
  <? } ?>  <!--Cierra el while-->
  </table>
 </div> <!--Cierra el container-->
 </div>
  <br>
  <?php

  }echo "";

  ?>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vas a hacer exactamente lo mismo. Lo único diferente es que los datos que recibirás de tu BD estarán en los values de los inputs. Un ejemplo sería así:

```
<input type="text" class="loquesea" value="<?php echo $resultado['nombre']; ?>">
<input type="tel" class="loquesea" value="<?php echo $resultado['telefono']; ?>">
<input type="number" class="loquesea" value="<?php echo $resultado['total']; ?>">
```

Comment: muchas gracias ;)

Comment: Si resolvi tu pregunta, estaríabien que la pusieras como correcta pra ayudar a más personas a encontrarla màs rapido

Comment: Amigo tengo una duda en db->obtenerfilas que toca poner??

Comment: @LenninJesús Crea una nueva pregunta con tu código para tener más información!

Comment: Lo hice, he investigado otra forma entonces, tengo otro problema, espero que usted puede ayudarme Gracias @Hoose

Answer (score 1):

Debes poner el siguiente código el value de cada input que se rellenará:

`<?php echo $_GET['nombre_del_campo']; ?>`

Teniendo en cuenta que remplazarás "nombre_del_campo" por el nombre del input.

Answer (score 1):

Para que te salgan las coincidencias tendrías que hacer una busqueda sin tener que recargar la página, podrías usar AJAX para eso.

Aquí te pasó un breve y bien explicado ejemplo y más para tu caso.

https://mimentevuela.wordpress.com/2015/08/09/busqueda-instantanea-con-ajax-php-y-mysql/

Comment: Te recomendaria que agregaras codigo en lugar de un enlace, ya que estos son propensos a dejar de funcionar

Comment: Ivan, tienes razón. Pero verifiqué el enlace antes de postearlo.